# Specify condition in script in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, conditional-statements

first screenshot:

[image]

second screen shot:

[image]
I have pasted the complete code of script:

```
 <script>
     var SITEURL = "{{ url('/') }}";
      var today = moment();
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                     defaultView: 'week',
      
                      visibleRange: {
                      start: moment('<? echo $dateFrom;?>T00:00:00'),
                      end: moment('<? echo $dateTo;?>T24:00:00')
                    } ,
                    header: {
                        
                        left: '',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: ''
                      },
                    
                    editable: true,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
                       views: {
                        week: {
                           
                             type: 'timeline',
                            slotLabelInterval: { hours: 24},
                            slotDuration: { hours: 24},
                        }
                    },                
                    resourceLabelText: 'Time Slot',
                  
                    resources: [
                        
                        { id: '1', title: '08:00 - 08:30' , eventColor: 'green'},
                        { id: '2', title: '08:30 - 09:00', eventColor: 'green' },
                        { id: '3', title: '09:00 - 09:30', eventColor: 'green'  },
                        { id: '4', title: '09:30 - 10:00', eventColor: 'green'},
                        { id: '5', title: '10:30 - 11:00', eventColor: 'green' },
                        { id: '6', title: '11:30 - 12:00', eventColor: 'green'},
                        { id: '7', title: '12:30 - 13:00', eventColor: 'green' },
                        { id: '8', title: '13:30 - 14:00', eventColor: 'green'},
                        { id: '9', title: '14:30 - 15:00', eventColor: 'green' },
                        { id: '10', title: '15:30 - 16:00', eventColor: 'green'},
                        { id: '11', title: '16:30 - 17:00', eventColor: 'green' },
                        { id: '12', title: '17:30 - 18:00', eventColor: 'green'},
                        { id: '13', title: '18:30 - 19:00', eventColor: 'green' },
                        
                        ],
      
                    events: [
                      <?php
         
           foreach ($data as $sl => $valuegm){
             
  
         ?>
                      { id: '<?php echo $valuegm->id; ?>', 
                      resourceId: '<?php echo $valuegm->timeslot_id; ?>',
                      start: '<?php echo $valuegm->date; ?>',
                      end: '<?php echo $valuegm->date;?>', title: '',
                      description: '<?php if(!$valuegm->doctor_id==null)
                      {echo "<b>".$valuegm->get_doctor->name."</b><br/>".$valuegm->get_doctor->get_specialty->name."<br/>
                      Mobile:".$valuegm->get_doctor->mobile."<br/>
                      Address:".$valuegm->get_doctor->address."<br/>";?><? if(!$valuegm->get_doctor->email==null)
                      { echo "Email:".$valuegm->get_doctor->email."<br/>";}?>
                      <? echo "City:".$valuegm->get_doctor->get_city->description."<br/>";?>
                      <? if(!$valuegm->get_doctor->area_id==null){ echo "Area:".$valuegm->get_doctor->get_area->name."<br/>";}?>
                      <?}else{echo "<b>".$valuegm->get_pharmacy->name."</b><br/>Mobile:".$valuegm->get_pharmacy->mobile."<br/>
                      Address:".$valuegm->get_pharmacy->address."<br/>";?>
                      <? if(!$valuegm->get_pharmacy->email==null){ echo "Email:".$valuegm->get_pharmacy->email."<br/>";}?>
                      <? echo "City:".$valuegm->get_pharmacy->get_city->description."<br/>";?>
                      <? if(!$valuegm->get_pharmacy->area_id==null){ echo "Area:".$valuegm->get_pharmacy->get_area->name."<br/>";}?><?}?>
                      
                    
                    
                    
                      
                      <?php $f = $valuegm->rating; if ($f == 1) { echo "Rating: Positive"; } elseif ($f == 2) { echo "Rating: Netural"; }elseif ($f == 3) { echo "Rating: Negative"; }?>
                      
                      
                    
                    
                    
                      
                      <?php echo "<p>".$valuegm->feedback."</p>";?><br/>',url: SITEURL + '/search/<?php echo $valuegm->id;?>/<?php echo $dateFrom;?>/<?php echo $dateTo;?>'},
                      <?php }?>],
                      
                                          
        eventRender: function(event, element) { 
            element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.description ); 
            
        } 
      
                });
   </script>
```

Actually, I am working with this part:

If the rating is positive the background color should be green.
If the rating is negative the background color should be red.

Actually, I am working on how to specify the background color based on the rating of the doctor in the below code.

```
resources: [

                    { id: '1', title: '08:00 - 08:30' , eventColor: 'green'},
                    { id: '2', title: '08:30 - 09:00', eventColor: 'green' },
                    { id: '3', title: '09:00 - 09:30', eventColor: 'green'  },
                    { id: '4', title: '09:30 - 10:00', eventColor: 'green'},
                    { id: '5', title: '10:30 - 11:00', eventColor: 'green' },
                    { id: '6', title: '11:30 - 12:00', eventColor: 'green'},
                    { id: '7', title: '12:30 - 13:00', eventColor: 'green' },
                    { id: '8', title: '13:30 - 14:00', eventColor: 'green'},
                    { id: '9', title: '14:30 - 15:00', eventColor: 'green' },
                    { id: '10', title: '15:30 - 16:00', eventColor: 'green'},
                    { id: '11', title: '16:30 - 17:00', eventColor: 'green' },
                    { id: '12', title: '17:30 - 18:00', eventColor: 'green'},
                    { id: '13', title: '18:30 - 19:00', eventColor: 'green' },

                    ],
```

i have specifyed the particular line for fetching  review(please refer the complete code for
better  understanding). please try figure out this:

```
              <?php $f = $valuegm->rating; if ($f == 1) { echo "Rating: Positive"; } elseif ($f == 2) { echo "Rating: Netural"; }elseif ($f == 3) { echo "Rating: Negative"; }?>
```

Comment: As far as I can see, your `resources` are labelled as "Time Slots" in the picture. That means, they represent the whole row. That would mean, that every event in a resource has to have the same color. Is that what you want?

Comment: @shaedrich No, please check the second screenshot that I have attached. In that, if the review is positive, the background color is green that is completely fine, But the background color should be red for the negative review that is the thing I am actually trying. please try to sort out this. please refer to the complete code for complete understanding and also do check the particular line at the end that fetches review.